# What percentage of German words are nearly identical to English words?

Tags: etymology, loanword, false-friends

As I continue to self-study German by reading the German press, I keep encountering in newspapers more and more German words that look similar to and have the same meaning as English words. Some of the recent examples are:

> *koordinieren, explodieren, das Meeting, das Dokument, kriminell*
>   *coordinate, explode, the meeting, the document, criminal*

So, I wonder if it is possible to approximate the percentage of such words in German (regardless of origin, be it English, Latin or other).

### Details

- The **corpus** should be **journalistic** texts, not literature, spoken language, scientific or technical texts. [COSMAS2](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/cosmas2/projekt/referenz/korpora.html) mostly consists of such, but one would have to exclude, e.g., Goethe’s works, Grimm’s fairytales and anything with *Belletristik* in the name of the corpus.
- All types of words count except for high-frequency closed-class particles (e.g. *in*) and names, i.e. mostly **verbs, adjectives and nouns**.
- We’re interested in lexemes that **occur at all** in the corpus (*occurrence*) and not how often they do (relative or absolute *frequency*). The ratio is based on lemmas, not inflected word forms.
- Common **Germanic origins** do not count if the words were affected by the High German consonant shift (e.g. *foot* vs. *Fuß/Pfote*). No difference is made between Germanic, Romance, Greek or non-Indoeuropean etymology.
- **False friends** do not count, but a slightly different meaning of cognates is okay as long as there’s overlap and they may be the less common synonym.

Comment: In order to address your question, I don't think you can tell. That said, I guess it's around 80-90%. Technically, words that are of Germanic roots probably have a counterpart. Words based on Latin may exist in both languages, too, but there's a good chance that Germans do not know the word. Many Latin-based words are of a very high register or technical terms. Considering this and looking only at words that are used in everyday language, the percentage drops to maybe 20% or 30%. Or maybe still 50%?! :D

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "Latin-based words are of a very high register"?

Comment: I was looking for a term other than "formal", because "formal" wouldn't be quite correct either. Sometimes I look up an English word in a dictionary and it suggests the same word in German. German monolingual dictionaries second that it is a German word, but I've never heard it, much less used it. But I can also hardly think of any occupation where such a word would be a "technical term". I can't give you an example though, I always forget the words shortly after I looked them up.

Comment: Do *Hand, Fuß, Haupt, Finger* count? *Bein* probably not if you want the meaning to be the same.  What about *studieren*? What about *Exempel*, *originär*?

Comment: Do you want to know the percentage of words which occur in a typical document like a newspaper or do you want to know the percentage of all words, which would include the question how extensiv the dictionary is? In either way, you can pick 100 words by random, order them according to your criteria, and have a rough estimation. For a better estimation take 1000 words.

Comment: @Carsten S: I  wouldn't include Fuß, Haupt, and Bein into the list, because their meaning would not be immediately clear to an English speaker.

Comment: @user unknown: I would be more interested in real-life words, like the ones one finds in a newspaper article. Very useful hint about choosing random words.

Comment: @Em1 The field of medicince is a very good example. Contrary to English, where Latin terms are routinely used even by laypersons, we often have a different set of expressions in German: Take _esophagus_ => Speiseröhre or _laryngitis_ => Kehlkopfentzündung etc. There are many more. (Don't get me started on the whole female reproductive system.)

Comment: what about *das Boot, das Kind, das Gift, der Brief, der Hall, die Last, die List, and die Not?*

Comment: Well known false friends, every one of them?

Comment: no, I copied them from an article :) my point is that the problem requires a tedious math. I am interested in the answer myself

Comment: The linguistic term you for what you are looking for is *[cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate).* Some etymological dictionaries list cognates, so you “only” need to find such a dictionary and count how many German words have English cognates listed (and maybe weight the results with the frequency of the word in everyday language).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, he is not interested in cognates in general.

Comment: The parameters in the question are underspecified from a scientific, linguistic point of view. I’ve added some details that I think I could deduct from it and the OP’s comments. Please edit and update as appropriate, so this doesn’t need to be closed.

Comment: Here's a (probably everything else but exhaustive, but already quite long) list to start with: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Englisch/%C3%84hnliche_W%C3%B6rter_Englisch%E2%80%93Deutsch . Sometimes I wonder what you *cannot* find on the net....

Comment: Hier findet man auch eine Liste: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortgleichung

Comment: Wie ähnlich? 1. Ein Deutscher, der Englisch lernt, erkennt eine Ähnlichkeit bei einem neuen Wort. (zum Beispiel foot = Fuß). 2. Ein Engländer, der versucht, eine deutsche Zeitung zu entziffern, ohne jegliche Deutschkentnisse, wird "Fuß" nicht erkennen, aber "kriminell" wird wohl erkannt.